# Trying to implement multiple keyword search but unable to get the desire results

Tags: php, mysql, arrays

I am trying to implement a multiple and keyword search in my application, but it searches only for the last word in the input and ignores the rest of the input can someone please help me with issue, below is my code...

```
$where_clause=array();
               if(!empty($vResume_screen))
    {
    // trim whitespace from the stored variable
               $trimmed = trim($vResume_screen);  
    // separate key-phrases into keywords
               $trimmed_array = explode(" ",$trimmed);
    // count keywords
               $trimm_total = count($trimmed_array);
                $i = 0;
                 $searchstring = '';
    // looping to get the search string
               foreach ($trimmed_array as $trimm)
    { 
        if ($i != 0 and $i != $wordcount)
        { 
            $searchstring .= " AND ";
        } 
        $searchstring .= "resume_text LIKE '%$trimm%'"; 

        // incrementing the value 
        $i = $i + 1; 
    }
         $where_clause[]="resume_text like '%".$searchstring."%'";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I just changed your code a little bit, take a look...

```
$where_clause=array();
if(!empty($vResume_screen))
    { 
        // separate key-phrases into keywords
        $trimmed_array = explode(" ", trim($trimmed));

        // count keywords
        $trimm_total = count($trimmed_array);

        $searchstring = '';

        // looping to get the search string
        foreach ($trimmed_array as $trimm)
        { 
           if (!empty($searchstring)) { 
               $searchstring .= " OR "; //If you want to put the same condition for different keywords, you need to use OR.
           } 
           $searchstring .= " resume_text LIKE '%" . $trimm . "%' "; 
    }
    array_push($where_clause, $searchstring);
}
```

- I dont know why you need the $where_clause to be an array but i did not change...

Comment: thanks, $where_clause needs to be an array because i have some other input fields in my application that I am passing along with the above input field to search the database. I would like to advance this search to boolean mode, if you could provide some guidance that would be of great help.

Comment: no problem...what do you mean advance the search to boolean mode? can you explain a little bit more what you need to do?